# ReSharper AutoCompletion for types not imported/referenced?

Tags: autocomplete, namespaces, resharper

I have a class, class UserTools {} and when I want to use it before importing/referencing its namespace I have to type the exact name as "UserTools". If I type "usertools", ReSharper doesn't popup autocompletion or namespace referencing dialog.

Is there a way to make ReSharper incase-sensitive, or even better understand "usert" when related namespace is not imported?

(Okay if it would show all the types in the all namespaces it would be so slow, however it can very well show the namespaces in my current project without any overhead, given that I don't have a huge project.)

Comment: Did you try crtl+alt+space? Is it slow for you?

Comment: If it would make that automatic it would great. But this is better than nothing, thanks!